# combineLatest and async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Edit some mis-typed**

What i did

```
// in component
export class WhatIdidComponent implements OnInit {
  storeData$
  combine$;

  constructor(
      private store: Store<AppState>
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
      this.storeData$ = this.store.pipe(select((state: AppState) => state['p']['reviews']), share());
      this.combine$ = combineLatest(
         //I inserted async storeData$ variable in combineLatest
         this.storeData$,
         this.route.params.pipe(/*any operator*/)
      )
  }
}
```

//d

```
//in template.html
<ng-container *ngIf="(storeData$ | async) as data; else loading">
     // not working properly when this.storeData$ is in combineLatest
     {{data.blah}}
</ng-container>
```

storeData$ with async pipe is not working when i insert `this.storeData` in `combineLatest`

I thought that this.storeData$ was nothing to do with `combineLatest`. because `this.storeData$` is `this.storeData$`.

but it seemed to be related to `combineLatest`. Why? and How to solve this?

What i want is

1. work properly with this.storeData and async pipe.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Can you clarify the questions, and the goals a bit? What does it mean "I want to work properly with X" - what's "proper"?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal that you wanna achieve with it? And why do you need combineLatest for, what do you wanna do with that one?

Comment: I want to know why `this.store` and `async pipe` are not responding in `template.html`
when i put this.storeData$ in `combineLatest`. the problem was the response of this.store and async pipe.  forget about my `combineLatest` question @Zlatko

Comment: Actually those are responding at first in `template.html. but after that. not responding. So I refreshed browser it works at first. and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a multicast subject with `share` that subscribes to your source (this.store) as soon as you subscribe to your `combineLatest` observable. This causes so-called 'late subscribers' to miss the notification of the original observable. Late subscribers in this case are all other subscribers except for the first one, therefore also your async pipe.

Your choices are to either drop the `share` pipe to maintain a cold observable or use e.g. `shareReplay(1)`  instead to create a caching behaviour.

Comment: I need some time to understand,  But It works! Thanks. and thank you for specific answer